# String + an incremental value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, web, styles

I've added comments at the middle of the code. Please help me If you can, I have to deliver the product today.

```
 if (a === 3) { //this would be how many of the answers further the action
                 var starting = 2; // for an example: yes or no; two of the answers go to no, one goes to yes. 
                 //                                  we take 2 as a starting point /you can set these individually for each scenario;
                 if (starting === 2) {
                     for (i = 0; i < starting; i++) {
                         answers[i] = 1; //sets the two checking points of the answer to the no, remaining yes;

 document.getElementById("btn" + i).style.backgroundColor = "red";

     // the problem lies here
    // I tried multiple ways but none of them worked so far
    //i want to apply the style change to multiple buttons at once.

                     }

                     alert(answers);

                     for (i = 0; i < starting; i++) {
                         if (answers[i] == 1) {

                         }
                     }

                 }
             }
```

The problem is that the name of the button which is btn and the buttons are named as btn1, btn2,btn3; I want the for loop to change it to all of the buttons, however the string literal at the id doesn't recognize the i;

Example: "btn" + i; = change the style of the btn1

I fixed it guys. The mistake was that the for loop starts at 1; 
And I have named the id of the buttons wrong. Novice mistake! :)

Comment: ya .surely we help you .please add some working example or markup html

Comment: What is the error you get, if any?

Comment: `if (starting = 2)` needs to be `if (starting === 2)`

Comment: Umm the javascript doesn't load at all.I tried this too:   document.getElementById("btn" + i).style.backgroundColor = "red";

Comment: Works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/efzdmk6a/ Did you check the browser console for error messages? Edit after edit: sounds like you need `var n = "btn" + (i + 2);`

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  if (document.getElementById("btn" + i) != undefined)
    document.getElementById("btn" + i).style.backgroundColor = "red";


}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="btn3">
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="btn1">
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="btn2">
```

The problem is your button id starts from **btn1** and your code starts from **0** which is not located in your html so either add a check before setting background color or start your loop from 1

> `if (document.getElementById("btn" + i) != undefined)`